# Polars DF takes up lots of RAM

Tags: dataframe, performance, python-polars

I'm running a python script that analyses a dataframe (loaded from a parquet file).
I've ran my program using the `memory_profiler` package to see the mem signature it has - on 2 DataFrames with a size of 9 & 20 mb (obtained by using `df.estimated_size()`), I'm seeing a whopping 280 mb memory usage (also ran on docker and analyzed statistics to make sure im in a clean env).

So I've created a simple script that just loads the data into a dataframe - I'm still seeing the 20mb df increasing mem usage by 70mb, and the 9mb df by 30mb.

These are the results of the `estimated_size` and the `memory_profiler` with the script:

```
f 20.546353340148926 # estimated size, mb
g 9.469635009765625 # estimated size, mb


 7     32.8 MiB     32.8 MiB           1   @profile
 8                                         def run():
 9                                         
10    105.1 MiB     72.2 MiB           1       pldf_f = pl.read_parquet('./benchmark/data/f_mock_data_100-records.parquet')
11    136.1 MiB     31.0 MiB           1       pldf_g = pl.read_parquet('./benchmark/data/g_mock_data_100-records.parquet')
12                                         
13    136.2 MiB      0.1 MiB           1       print(f'f {pldf_f.estimated_size("mb")}')
14    136.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print(f'g {pldf_g.estimated_size("mb")}')
```

I thought Polars is supposed to have a low mem impact, and am seeing results of 3x the dataframe size.

This is of course just mock test data, I'm expected to analyze records in the hunders-of-thousands range if not millions.

Am I reading the results wrong?

Comment: Now do the same test with pandas and then do it again with 3GB and 7GB dfs to see how things scale. So you'll have small DFs polars vs pandas and big(ger) DFs polars vs pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Memory allocators

Memory shown by a process is the aggregate of the memory in data structures. During heap allocation and deallocation, the allocator will keep hold of the memory pages and not return them to the OS.

This is desired behavior as the memory allocator can use that memory later and therefore this will improve performance.

### N x table size

3x a table size is actually pretty good. Consider you have a memory buffer and you need to deserialize that data into another buffer, that already gives you 2X.

### All data in RAM

Used RAM is not so bad, it is there to be used. We could optimize for minimal RAM usage but that would hurt performance and would be a waste of available resources.

If your data doesn't fit into RAM, try the polars streaming API. This will process the data in batches, spill to disk when needed and allows you to materialize on disk rather than in RAM.

### Shrink

You can shrink the `DataFrame` size by calling `df.shrink_to_fit()`, but I would advice against it if it is not needed.

Comment: So I'm still dealing with this. 
While I understand your answer, I have a service running that processes ~2gb of data. After finishing, I'm deleteing ALL of my refs to the df (also tried manually garbage collecting it), but the mem usage never drops. 

Another weird thing is that issuing the exact same request results in another rise in RAM usage (which negates the point about the RAM being saved for the future). 

Any idea how I can clear this ?

Comment: You cannot clear this in python. The memory allocator keeps it for the duration of the process. If you are on windows you can try tune mimalloc. Or jemalloc on linux.

Comment: Side question: is it better or worse than pandas, since it's the most direct competitor?

Comment: @EricBurel performance wise Polars is WAY better than Pandas. We've managed to shrink a runtime of close to an hour to a few minutes. Assuming you take the "issues" of Polars into account and build your code around them, I'd definitely go with Polars.